# How to use an Integer when computing a Float

Tags: haskell

```
totalPrice :: Product -> Integer -> Float    
totalPrice product x = case product of  

    Ramen    
    | x <= 10 -> 2 * x    
    | x <= 30 -> 1.8 * x   
    | x <= 100 -> 1.5 * x   
    | x <= 200 -> 1.4 * x   
    | x > 200 -> 1.35 * x   
    | otherwise -> 0   

Chips
    | x <= 2 -> 3 * x
    | x <= 5 -> 2.95 * x
    | x <= 10 -> 2.7 * x
    | x <= 20 -> 2.5 * x
    | x > 20 -> 2.35 * x
    | otherwise -> 0
```

When I compile this code it get error "Couldn't match expected type ‘Double’ with actual type ‘Integer’"

Any suggestions?

Comment: paste the code as text, and make sure you indent the code.

Comment: As a rule of thumb to help you decide what to look at when debugging problems in future: if you get a type error ("cannot match expected type ... with actual type ..."), it usually means that there is no issue with your *syntax*. In this example the problem had noting to do with guards or cases, you just used an operation that wasn't supported by your type. If you had a problem with the guard or case syntax Haskell wouldn't be able to figure out enough of what you were trying to do to even begin checking types.

Answer (score 3):

`x` is an `Integer`, and you are multiplying it with decimal values to produce a `Float`. The operands and result of arithmetic operators like `(*)` must be of the same type, and you must convert between types explicitly.

```
totalPrice product y = case product of
  Ramen
    | x <= 10 -> 2 * x
    ...
  where
    x = fromInteger y
```

Comment: Also, using floats for money is often dangerous. I'd say just use an integer number of pennies.